# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings or only AppSettings?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, expressionbuilder

I have question: when I to use `<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xxx"] %>` and `<%$ AppSettings: xxx %>`.

Sometimes when I use `<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xxx "] %>` a I got the following error: "Server tags cannot contain <% … %> constructs". Then a put `<%$ AppSettings: xxx %>` and it works.

Like this example:
Error:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Literal9" Text="<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xxx"] %>"></asp:Literal>
```

Working:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Literal9" Text='<%$ AppSettings: xxx %>'></asp:Literal>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs not because you're switching between `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` and `AppSettings`, but because of the symbol used after `<%`.  You can't have code rendering markup inside a server-side control that renders markup.  The second way works because it evaluates the expression prior to server-side control render.

My preference is to always use `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`, because it's more clear as to what the code is accessing.